# How can I debug 'zend_mm_heap corrupted' for my php extension

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, php-extension

**The Problem**

I've written a php extension (PHP 5.3) which appears to work fine for simple tests but the moment I start making multiple calls it I start seeing the error:

> zend_mm_heap corrupted

Normally through a console or apache error log, I also sometimes see the error

> [Thu Jun 19 16:12:31.934289 2014] [:error] [pid 560] [client 127.0.0.1:35410] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 139678164955264 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

**What I've tried to do**

I've tried find the exact spot where the issue occurs but it appears to occurs between the destructor being called for my php class that calls the extension but before the constructor runs the first line of the constructor (note, I have mainly used phpunit to diagnose this, if I run it in a browser it will usually work once and then throw the error to the log on the next attempt with a 'The connection was reset' in my browser window so no output.

I've tried adding debug lines with memory_get_usage and installing the extension memprof but all output fails to show any serious memory issues and I've never seen a memory usage greater than 8mb.

I've looked at other stack overflow posts with regard to changing php settings to deal with zend_mm_corrupted issue, disabling/enabling garbage collection without any degree of success.

**What I'm looking for**

I realise that there is not enough information here to possibly know what is causing what I presume to be a memory leak, so what I want to know is what are possible and probable causes of my issue and how can I go about diagnosing this issue to find where the problem is.

*Note:*

I have tried building my extension with --enable-debug but it comes as unrecognised argument.

**Edit: Valgrind**

I have run over it with valgrind and got the following output:

> --24803-- REDIR: 0x4ebde30 (__GI_strncmp) redirected to 0x4c2dd20 (__GI_strncmp)
>   --24803-- REDIR: 0x4ec1820 (__GI_stpcpy) redirected to 0x4c2f860 (__GI_stpcpy)
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>   ==24803==
>   ==24803== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==24803==     in use at exit: 2,401 bytes in 72 blocks
>   ==24803==   total heap usage: 73 allocs, 1 frees, 2,417 bytes allocated
>   ==24803==
>   ==24803== Searching for pointers to 72 not-freed blocks
>   ==24803== Checked 92,624 bytes
>   ==24803==
>   ==24803== LEAK SUMMARY:
>   ==24803==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==24803==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==24803==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==24803==    still reachable: 2,401 bytes in 72 blocks
>   ==24803==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==24803== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
>   ==24803== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
>   ==24803==
>   ==24803== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
>   --24803--
>   --24803-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1
>   ==24803==
>   ==24803== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)

This suggests to me that perhaps the issue isn't a memory leak but am not certain on this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your program does have heap memory corruption. This is is bit difficult to find by looking out your code snippet or faulty call stack. You may want run your program under some dynamic tools(Valgrind, WindDBG/Pageheap) to track the actual source of error.

> $ valgrind --tool=memcheck --db-attach=yes ./a.out

This way Valgrind would attach your program in the debugger when your first memory error is detected so that you can do live debugging(GDB). This should be the best possible way to understand and resolve your problem.

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   139678164955264 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

It looks like somewhere in your program signed to unsigned conversion is getting executed. Normally allocators have size parameter of unsigned type so it interpret the negative value to be very large type and under those scenario, allocation would fail.